# WPF FlowDocument :: How Can I Define Custom Templates for the Child Paragraph, Run, etc

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox, datatemplate

I'm fairly new to WPF, so please bear with me.

I am trying to customize the presentation of the various elements of a `FlowDocument` in a `RichTextBox` (RTB).  WPF controls are lookless, so as I understand it I should be able to define the look for every child in the `Document`.

Would I define the template for this in the RTB?  Separate templates for each item (`Paragraph`, `Section`, `Run`, etc) as resources?  <strike>Let's say, for sake of argument, that I want a red border around every `Section`, the word "Paragraph:" before every `Paragraph` with a `Margin="5"`, and every `Run` to be in Consolas.</strike> (see edit one)

**EDIT ONE**:

I learn more here from asking the *wrong* question than the right one.  It seems I never ask what I'm really trying to do the first time out the gate.  Who knows, maybe I'll learn.

I am trying to define a `DataTemplate` or an `ItemTemplate` (I think) similar to a `ListBox`.  The ultimate goal is a "source view" HTML editor in an RTB.  I want a Paragraph XAML element to render like this in the RTB:

```
<p>
  Lorem ipsum stackus overflowum 
</p>
```

... and a Run would render like this:

```
<span style="font-weight:bold">clarity is important when asking questions</span>
```

... and so on with the different XAML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Some of that you can do with styles
E.G.

```
<Paragraph Style="{StaticResource Par2}">
    This is not a substitute for training.
</Paragraph>

<Style x:Key="Par1short"  TargetType="Paragraph">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,4,0,0" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Par2"  TargetType="Paragraph">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="30,7,0,0" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Par2short"  TargetType="Paragraph">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="30,4,0,0" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Par3"  TargetType="Paragraph">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="45,7,0,0" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Par3short"  TargetType="Paragraph">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="45,4,0,0" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Par4"  TargetType="Paragraph">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="60,7,0,0" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Par4short"  TargetType="Paragraph">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="60,4,0,0" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Par5"  TargetType="Paragraph">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="75,7,0,0" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Par5short"  TargetType="Paragraph">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="75,4,0,0" />
</Style>
```

Now the word Paragraph: before every paragraph I don't think you can do that with styles

Comment: please see my edits; you answered the question I asked, but I really phrased my question poorly.

Comment: You do know if you leave off the key a style will effect the TargetType.  You question is still not clear to me.

Comment: So if you were to bind a bunch of POCO objects to a listbox, you could define a custom template to use to render each one, using whatever StackPanels, Grids, Textboxes etc. that you want.  Can I do that to the Paragraph elements in a FlowDocument?

Comment: @ScottSEA I don't think so.  It is not like you are binding to a collection with and get to use items templates.  But just because I don't know how does not mean it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't apply templates to these elements because they don't inherit from ControlTemplate.