# WPF: Defining "Templates" for Elements Not Inherited From Control

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, controltemplate, flowdocument

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680625/wpf-flowdocument-how-can-i-define-custom-templates-for-the-child-paragraph-r) I tried to find a way to re-template the contents of a FlowDocument.  I've done several hours of research, and eventually come to this documentation on Control.Template property:

> The ControlTemplate specifies the appearance of a Control; if a Control does not have a ControlTemplate, **the Control will not appear in your application**.

*I call shenanigans.*

The `Paragraph`, `Run`, `Section`, `List`, `Table`, and so forth all "appear in my application" but since they inherit from `System.Windows.ContentElement` instead of `System.Windows.Controls.Control` none of them have a `Template` property that I can use to redefine the visual tree of the control.

Is there any way to change the visual presentation of these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to template the ContentElements, and its not intended.

But you can use

```
<BlockUIContainer/>
```

for templated Controls within a FlowDocument.

Comment: Sadly the answer is sometimes a simple "No".  Thank you.